# How to add permissions to windows/mac flutter app

Tags: flutter, imagepicker, flutter-form-builder

Good day,

I added these permissions to my Info.plist for ios

```
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Upload images for screen background</string>
  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Upload image from camera for screen background</string>
  <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Post videos to profile</string>
```

How do I add something like this for macOS and windows to allow permission to access camera and gallery

Comment: Could be useful to open up a bit of what you are trying to achieve. Are you using perhaps some plugin?

Comment: @user18309290 I am using the formbuilder image picker and it crashed on ios everytime I tried to choose an image until in added the code above but windows still crashes because I havent allowed permission how do I add permission like I did on ios

Comment: If you are using this https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker, it doesn't support Windows or macOS.

Comment: @user18309290 no im using https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_image_picker

Comment: Of course, but the same thing doesn't support Windows or macOS.